# Problema em um Breadcrumb utilizando "direction: rtl"

Tags: html, css, front-end

Estou com problema utilizando o "direction: rtl" e gostaria da ajuda de vocês.
Criei um breadcrumb, quando ele atinge o tamanho limite da tela o final dele permanece em tela e o ínicio é cortado. Foi a única forma que consegui fazer, sem a utilização de algum JS. O problema é que quando o primeiro nível de pasta começa com um número, os números são jogados pro final (mesmo sendo o primeiro elemento).

Criei o código no https://jsfiddle.net/andersonmelo/3ge59bLe/4/ para vocês darem uma olhada.
Deixei em comentário um gambito que "resolve" o problema, mas eu não gostaria de resolver dessa forma... alguém consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Qual efeito voce gostaria de atingir com esse rtl no breadcrumb ?

retirando a linha 28 do css ele se acerta, porém não sei o que você esta tentando  fazer.

Comment: Quando você dizer o resize da área, o final do breadcrumb permanece em tela, e o inicio é cortado (ficando "por trás" do "Home"). O rtl faz essa inversão.

Answer (score 0):

O uso de `float:left;` fazia perder o efeito do rtl;

Fiz o alinhamento utilizando *inline-block* e retirei o flutuação. Aparentemente melhorou.

https://jsfiddle.net/3ge59bLe/5/

Comment: É que na verdade eu preciso que o "Home" permaneça na frente e aquela pasta com número esteja na mesma ordem (no início). Tirando os números da primeira pasta ela fica na forma correta.